# Custom Personal Action Menu

Tags: custom-masterpage

In Sharepoint 2013, is there a way to override the **personal action menu** and implement my own customized menu?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a way. Use a delegate control and extend the control responsible for generating the personal action menu, overwriting the resulting menu with your own items. Oh, and by the way, the SE overlords stipulate that I should comment below your original question if I need clarification for what you are needing. They fail to realize that only someone with 50 reputation can do that. So, if you need more information that I've provided please revise your question. And if the overlords want more participation from casual users of this site they will change the 50 reputation policy. It is stupid and counter-productive.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Only those with 50 reputation can comment on posts so how do you propose I do that? Also, the question was "is there a way" to which I accurately responded with an affirmative answer and some direction on how to discover that. He did not ask for more details. Perhaps I answered his question exactly, that there was a way and he is enough of a self-starter to do his own work instead of trolling for someone else to do it. I find your downvote over-reaching. But, honestly, I could not care less. The reputation thing on this site is ignorant. I doubt I will help anyone else if this is how it is.